# Terms and conditions on registration form in magento2

Tags: magento2, terms-and-conditions, customer-registration

I want to add Terms and Conditions checkobox on Account registration page in magento2.
User should accept the terms and condition before creating an account

Answer (score 0):

try with below file and update in following files:  `/vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/form/register.phtml` (Append below code)

```
<?php   
     if (!$block->getAgreements()) {
            return;
        }

        /** @var \Magento\CheckoutAgreements\Model\ResourceModel\Agreement\Collection $argeementsCollection */
        $argeementsCollection = $block->getAgreements();
        $agreementMappedArray = [];
        /** @var \Magento\CheckoutAgreements\Model\Agreement $agreement */
        foreach ($argeementsCollection as $agreement) {
            if ($agreement->getIsActive()) {
                $agreementMappedArray[] = [
                    'mode' => $agreement->getMode(),
                    'agreementId' => $agreement->getAgreementId(),
                    'checkboxText' => $agreement->getCheckboxText(),
                    'content' => $agreement->getContent()
                ];
            }
        }
        $agreementJson = json_encode($agreementMappedArray);
        ?>
        <div data-bind="scope: 'checkout-agreements-component-scope'" class="checkout-agreements-block">
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        </div>
```

Add below script :

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
 {
    "*": {
        "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
            "components": {
                "checkout-agreements-component-scope": {
                    "component": "Magento_CheckoutAgreements/js/view/checkout-agreements",
                    "agreements": <?php /* @noEscape */ echo $agreementJson; ?>,
                    "isVisible": true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

I hope its work for you.